# Passing HttpStatusCodes throughout different layers in web api application

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, http-status-codes

I'm writing a web api app that I have divided into various projects such Web, Services, DataAccess  - so basically the web api controller contacts the service layers which then can access the data access layer.

I was returning just a bool to let me know if the data access method has completed ok, then picking this up in the service layer and then back to the controller...where I can then respond with a HTTPStatusCode of 200, or 500 etc..depending whether or not the operation has returned a true or false.

Instead of bool is it good practice to use HttpStatusCodes instead...or should HTTP status codes only be used in the Controller - to return a response to the app that's calling the web api or should it be something else?

Thanks,

Comment: Perhaps a code example would help, but this question seems that of an opinion and not concrete.  That said, my confusion here is if your service returns boolean, how does the service return the actual data to be returned to the client?  Again, code example would help!

Comment: Hi, ok I could just be writing something to the database that doesn't return anything. So the bool would just be to respond that it was able to complete the write ok. There's no need to return any new record ID etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all classes should have the least possible knowledge of the world around them. Suppose you implement [the repository pattern](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649690.aspx) to fetch data. Your repository (data access layer) should not even know about HTTP, nor it should expect to be a part of web application. Its only concern is accessing a particular table.

It’s difficult to suggest specific solution without understanding the big picture, but you may consider the following:

1. Raise an exception if your application depends on data that couldn’t be fetched. It’ll propagate as 500 response.
2. Use enum instead of bool to make code more readable.
3. Create DataResponse class to incapsulate result of data access operation. You may then use [the adapter pattern](http://www.dofactory.com/net/adapter-design-pattern) to adapt DataResponse to HttpResponse.

Comment: Thanks. Think I'll return an enum.

Comment: You're on the right track... For (1) 500 is ok if there is an app error. If the data is not found return 404, and if it was deleted return 410.

Answer (score 1):

Vague question, but I'll attempt an answer.

This really depends on the reason for separation between the layers, and what each layer is concerned with.  One question I would ask myself is why do you have a Service layer?  Is it because it contains the business logic?  Is it because intent is to have an option to reuse it outside WebAPI context?  Or do you expect Service layer to have dependency on WebAPI context (i.e. that it is a web request, and not service being reused say inside a winform.)

Most likely, you want to constrain dealing with HTTP particulars to the Controller (IMHO, this is obviously just my opinion).  But I'd refrain from using it as a hard and fast rule.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Yes, the service layer could potentially have Business logic as the project progresses.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be propagating http status codes down or up the line. If you do then you are injecting dependency on what you worked so hard to decouple. One of the great things about N-tier architecture is that yeah, your web layer may be primarily used for interacting with your service layer but what happens when you want to hook up a native mobile application to call it, or a windows service to call it, or a desktop app to call it. You are basically handicapping its potential by trying to persist that error up and down the chain.